# octave cov function with python (numpy?)

Tags: python, numpy, octave

Im trying to replicate the cov function as it works in octave: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cov.html

Where given:

```
F = [[3,4,5],[5,4,3],[1,1,1]]
```

Octave function will return:

```
cov(F)

ans =

   4   3   2
   3   3   3
   2   3   4
```

While the numpy function cov https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html doesnt work the same way. It returns:

```
np.cov(F)

array([[ 1., -1.,  0.],
       [-1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If I read the docs both should be calculating the covariance matrix, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Octave's `cov`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cov.html) treats rows as observations and columns as variables:

> If each row of x and y is an observation, and each column is a variable...

[`numpy.cov`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) defaults to the opposite behavior:

> **rowvar : *bool, optional***
>
> If *rowvar* is True (default), then each row represents a variable, with observations in the columns. Otherwise, the relationship is transposed: each column represents a variable, while the rows contain observations.

Specify `rowvar=False` when calling `numpy.cov` to get the Octave behavior.